# Syncing photos to iCloud and deleting them

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, photos, photos.app

I want to save all my photos to iCloud and then delete them from my iPhone.  How do I delete them from the iPhone while still keeping a copy on iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud is a **syncing** system and not a just a backup.

If you delete the pictures on your iPhone (assuming you're logged into the same iCloud account) you're also deleting the pictures in iCloud. This is **not** what you want to do.

Find a backup solution to keep your photos like Dropbox or Amazon Photos. Those will allow you upload your images without keeping them on your other devices.